# How to create a custom Info Window in xamarin forms google map

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, infowindow

I want to create a custom info window in my ios map,How can I implement this.I am using xamarin forms google map plugin to create  map.

Please Help me

I want a custom info window like this

[image]

Comment: any luck with iOS?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution

Comment: can you post the solution..

Comment: I am posted my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

I am achieving this by using Xamarin. Forms. Google Maps plugin, And I am implementing a Custom renderer for the infowindow design.

In the Xaml

```
  <maps:CustomMapiOS x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
  IsShowingUser="True" >                 
   </maps:CustomMapiOS>
```

Create a Custom Class in the portable project

```
 public class CustomMapiOS : Map
  {
    public CustomMapiOS()
    {

    }
  }
```

In iOS project create `CustomRendererMap`

```
 public class CustomRendererMap : MapRenderer
{
    private MapView mapView;

    UIView customPinView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            CustomMapiOS formsMap = (CustomMapiOS)e.NewElement;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            CustomMapiOS formsMap = (CustomMapiOS)e.NewElement;
            MapView nativeMap = Control as MapView;
            mapView = nativeMap;
            nativeMap.MarkerInfoWindow = new GMSInfoFor(markerInfoWindow);

        }
    }

    UIView markerInfoWindow(UIView view, Marker marker)
    {
        //infowindow design
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how you managed this for android too? @Lakshya

Comment: Are you sure this is a forms solution? you use <maps:CustomMapiOS in XAML